# Converting Korea 2000 coordinate system to WGS84?

Tags: coordinate-system, data, convert, geodetic, korea

I have coordinates in Korea 2000 EPSG:5181 projected coordinate system.

Is there a way to make a formulation in excel to convert these coordinates to lat long (WGS84)?

Comment: Which GIS software are you using?

Comment: Not using any GIS software. I want to know the formulas to transform the above mentioned coordinate system because i have a lot of data to convert so I want to make an excel sheet to transform the coordinates. Can you help? Thanks for your kind response

Comment: why you do not use gis software like gdal with batch processing ？

Comment: ... or use the official formulas from http://www.epsg.org/Portals/0/373-07-2.pdf page 45 ff with the parameters from http://epsg.io/5181

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into these two sources [Converting UTM to Latitude and Longitude (Or Vice Versa)](https://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/UsefulData/UTMFormulas.HTM)

[image]

and [Coordinate Systems in the Plane](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/docs/reference/CRC-formulas/node3.html)

[image]

> This program was recently updated using the formulas of Charles Karney (2010). His paper claims accuracy of a few nanometers. Excel has 15-digit accuracy, so the spreadsheet doesn't achieve that level, but is accurate to about 0.01mm.